# Inequality of quadratic function

Tags: inequality

I often find an inequality of the form

$ \lambda_{\min P}  \|x\|^2 \leq  x^T P x  \leq \lambda_{\max P} \|x\|^2 $,

where

$P=P^T$, $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm of $x\in\mathbb R^n$, and $\lambda_{\min P}$ and $\lambda_{\max P} $ are the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $P$, respectively.

1. How can it proofed or from which "rule" can this result be derived?
2. When for instance $ Q(x) = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}q_{11} & 0 \\ 0 &q_{22} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2
   \end{bmatrix}$ with $q_{11} \ll q_{22}$ then $Q(x) \leq q_{22} \|x\|^2$.

This seems conservative or isn't it? Is there an inequality where still both $q_{11}$ and $q_{22}$ appear on the right hand side of the $\leq$?

Comment: I assume that $P$ is supposed to be symmetric? Consider $x = (1,1)$ and $P = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Ok I see, yes then it should be assumed that P is symmetric. I corrected it above.

Comment: Can someone  give  any hint how to proof the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $P$ (e.g., when $P$ is symmetric) then given any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, you can write $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$ for some scalars $\alpha_i$. Letting $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalue corresponding to $v_i$ for each $i$, you have
$$
x^T P x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i^2 \|v_i\|^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i^2. 
$$
From here, you have
$$
\lambda_{\text{min}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i^2 \leq \lambda_{\text{max}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2
$$